# colocar uma imagem abaixo de colunas no Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-3, front-end

A estrutura esta correta, o problema, quando eu tento colocar uma imagem, a imagem vai lá para baixo junto com o `footer`, esse print que postei, é como é para ficar o resultado final. O código que estou postando está igual o print, exceto a imagem.

Código [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/5gp6x6t5)

SRC para adicionar a imagem:

`src="http://placehold.it/450x150"`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem alguma classe do *bootstrap* para adicionar a imagem em baixo da coluna 1 e coluna 2 ou tenho que fazer pelo *css*??

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo do que você pode fazer: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andredgusmao/h9dLjda8/).

Você tem que subdividir as colunas dessa forma:

```
|              col-md-8             |       col-md-4       |
| coluna 1 (md-6) | coluna 2 (md-6) | coluna 3 (col-md-12) |
|              imagem (md-12)       |
```